# Sequence of range space of compact operator stabilizes. Sheldon Axler MIRA Ex 10C 11

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Suppose $T$ is a compact operator from a Hilbert Space. Then for $a\neq 0$, we have that $\text{range}(T- aI)^{n-1}=\text{range}(T-aI)^{n}$ for some $n$ and $\ker(T-aI)^{m-1}=\ker(T-aI)^{m}$ for some $m$.

Firstly, if $a$ is a not an eigen value, then by Fredholm alternative we know that $T-aI$ is surjective.

So if $a$ is an eigenvalue, then we have that $\dim(\ker(T-aI))<\infty$. If I know look at the chain $\ker(T)\subseteq \ker(T^{2})\subseteq \ker(T^{3})...\subseteq$  I cannot use the finite dimensioinality in any helpful way because the chain is increasing and I only have an lower bound on the dimension.

I also know that if $\ker(T-aI)^{m}=\ker(T-aI)^{m-1}$ for some $m$, then we also will have that $\text{range}(T-aI)^{m-1}=\text{range}(T-aI)^{m}$ as this is a result from Linear Algebra. And also I can write $H=\ker(T-aI)^{m}\oplus \text{range}(T-aI)^{m}$.

But I am struggling to find a way in this problem. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** From the link given in the comment, I can do it if I can show that $\text{range}(T-aI)$ is closed. I have answered my own question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4880364/range-of-i-t-is-closed-for-t-being-a-compact-operator-in-a-banach-space?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Does this help [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3524250/if-t-is-compact-there-is-some-n-such-that-operatornameranget-alpha-i?rq=1)?